# AlertDialog not accepting dismiss code

Tags: android, dialog

I have a very small problem and which probably going to be easy for somebody with better knowledge than me but I have a problem with my `alertDialog` and the issue that when I write the code for the dialog to be dismiss under the set button method.  It gives me an syntax error and I have trying to figure out why for hours and I cant get around this simple problem. Can somebody assist me with this issue.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alertDialog.setTitle("ApplicationTitle");
alertDialog.setMessage("1st line" + "2nd line");
alertDialog.setMessage("1st line" + "2nd line");                     

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
 });
alertDialog.show();
```

this is the line of code I am talking about `alertDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder` is NOT an `AlertDialog`

Comment: What *exactly* is the error?  First rule of programming.  When telling someone else that there is an error, describe the error fully.  "Syntax error" could be one of many things.

Comment: you don't need to dismiss the dialog inside the handler, alert dialog will do it by default. just remove that line

Comment: @Simon the syntax error is underneath `dismiss` and it says "The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder"

Comment: @A--C Thanks very... I also have one more question and it is about my two line dialog.  When my dialog launches Its not in two lines it is just a big paragraph and I was just wondering if you could tell me why

Comment: @BobLast Firstly, `setMessage()` should overwrite the message each time. Secondly, you're missing a newline separator. On Android, `"1st line" + "\n2nd line"` usually works. Otherwise, try `"1st line" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "2nd line"`

Comment: @A--C It is still giving me the same results

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. Just use `dialog.cancel();` instead of `alertDialog.dismiss();`.
**EDIT**

You wanted the text to be in different lines. Why don't you try this and tell me if it works:

```
 StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    build.append("1st line")
    .append("\n")
    .append("2nd line")
    .append("\n")
    .append("3rd line");

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("ApplicationTitle");

    alertDialog.setMessage(build.toString());     


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
     });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I had found out that since I passed in `DialogInterface` There is no need for `alertDialog.dismiss();` because the dialog interface does this already.. But do you know by any chance how I can get my two line dialog to work properly.  When my dialog opens it displays it in a big paragraph and I already tried what one other person in the comments recommended.

Comment: You can even add set views to your DialogBox!